# How do i compress database table in sql server 2012 Standard Edition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

How do i compress database table in sql server 2012 Standard Edition.

The below query is working with my development machine having enterprise edition but live server having standard edition. And My database is too large and requires compression.

ALTER TABLE [dbo].Table1 REBUILD PARTITION = ALL
WITH 
(DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE
)

Comment: How large is "too large"?  How many records, how much disk space, etc.  What are the problems this size is causing?

Answer (score 5):

Data compression is an enterprise feature only, please see the following link for details of features available in each edition:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx

Comment: This is the reason I have asked, if anybody has any ideas to implement this in Standard Edition.

Comment: As i said, it's an enterprise only feature, the standard database engine just doesn't support this and so it will never work, unless you pay for an enterprise license and perform an edition upgrade.

Comment: I'm a DBA. I worked with a team once that implemented a 'software' version of compression for sqlserver 2005. The way this is done is that you have two columns.  myFieldNormal, myFieldCompressed. You read/write with the table with a DLL that can take the data in either format, and load up the objects that represent the rows cleanly regardless of where the data is. Then you write another job that compresses the data. Like I said, 'software' compression. Doing this is CHEAPER than sql server enterprise when you have 100+ cores in your enterprise. Also, diskdrives are cheaper than enterprise too.